# How do I set an icon using types in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, icons, jstree

I'm trying to set different icons for different nodes in jstree. I don't need to supply my own image file, the ones jstree comes with will work fine.

Here is part of the JSON string I'm supplying.

```
[{"id":"cb70bc8b-dcde-4c54-b69e-6cc331212cf1",
  "text":"Internal Reports",
  "type":"folder",
  "state":{"opened":false,"selected":false,"disabled":true},
  "children":
    [{"id":"7eac0622-f915-40b0-bb8b-00bf8fbe55a9",
      "text":"Client Service Center",
      "type":"folder",
      "state":{"opened":false,"selected":false,"disabled":true},
      "children":
        [{"id":"6a5a9552-f021-472e-b166-ff1ef4e00328",
          "text":"Navigator Report",
          "type":"file",
          "state":{"opened":false,"selected":false}
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Notice the first two parents have their type set to "folder" while the last child has a type of "file".

Here is my jquery function

```
    function reportJsonLoaded(response) {
        $("#ReportTree").jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': response
            },
            'types': {
                "folder": {
                    "icon": "jstree-icon jstree-folder"
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "jstree-icon jstree-file"
                }

            },
            "plugins": ["types"]
        });
    }
```

For some reason all the nodes show the default folder icon. Apparently I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I can see correct icons, here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ph3wdhds/

Comment: Bizarre. 

Here's the markup for the tag holding the icon in your jsfiddle link

`<i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-icon jstree-file jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>`

Here's the code from my project

`<i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>`

It doesn't even have the additional css labels

Comment: Wait, this can't be right. The version of jstree that's linked to from your jsfiddle page is 3.2.1 and it says it's from 2015. The the filename of the zip file I downloaded from from jstree.com says that it's 3.3.0, but the actual jstree.js file I'm linking to in the page doesn't even have a version number in it but it says it's from 2014.

Comment: I yanked the version he was using in the examples on his site and used that instead. It's working fine now. :/

Comment: Apparently I was using the one in the src folder of the zip when i was supposed to be using the one in the dist folder.